# force users to re-authorize to facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app that uses Facebook.

Many users already authorized to the app and have a valid access token.
I have made some changes to app permissions settings and I would like all users to re-authorized to the app.

Is there a way for me to force them all to reauthorize?